# How can I assign to an int variable something like class.array[i]?

Tags: c++

Sorry if my question is basic, but I got stuck.

This is my class.

```
class FidelityCard {
    public:
        const int id;           //constant attribute - generated based on noCards value
    private:
        char owner[50];
        string cardType;        //the service that provides the card (ex. Rompetrol, Mega Image, etc)

        int* points = NULL;         //points accumulated each time the client buys something
        int noPayments;         //number of payments done by the client

        static int noCards;     //incremented for each created card
}
```

This is the constructor used.

```
FidelityCard(const char* name, string cardName, int* existingPoints, int noPoints) : id(0) {...}
```

I'm trying to save in the variable somePoints the value of `card3.points[1]` using an operator(I think it's `operator[]`) but I don't know how.

```
int somePoints[] = { 15,5,10,30 };
int noPoints = 4;
FidelityCard card3("John", "ACME Inc", somePoints, noPoints);
int somePoints = card3[1];          //returns the number of points from the array on index 1
```

When I'm using this operator

```
int& operator[](int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < noPayments)
    {
        return points[index];
    }
    throw new exception("wrong index");
}
```

I get this error:

> Error C2040 'somePoints': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int [4]'

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Please provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and run ourselves without filling in any details or making any changes. Then explain what happens when you run your code and what you want it to do differently.

Comment: But if card3.points={ 15, 5,  20, 10) and I call int somePoints = card3[1], I want to have the value of 5 stored in somePoints..

Comment: @Foreastbtch That `card3` just pops up out of nowhere.  Please post  a [mcve] instead of describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: the question is how can I make an operator[] to store in somePoints the value of card.points[index]

Comment: @Foreastbtch We don't even know what `card` is.  I know it seems simple on your end to describe things, because you have the code in front of you and believe it should be obvious to us.  But we have no idea what your real code looks like, only by your description.

Comment: This is as you probably suspect a question that can be explained very clearly - if you'd provided the rest of your code. It won't help anyone else answering it in this state.

Comment: Your code is still not a [mre]

Comment: filling in the blanks your code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/nbTKE4, please provide a [mre]

Comment: In the latest code, you declare `somePoints` twice. Is that the cause of the error? Honestly I have no confidence in the code posted. It should not be this hard to post code, and make it clear what code causes what error.

Comment: @john That's it! This is a project for uni and my dumb teacher declared the same variable first as an array and now as an int. Thank you so much and sorry.

Comment: @Foreastbtch In your earlier post you had the line of code causing the error commented out. Because of that it's wasn't clear whether that was part of the code you were complaining about or not.

Answer (score 0):

So the obvious (?) problem here

```
int somePoints[] = { 15,5,10,30 };
int noPoints = 4;
FidelityCard card3("John", "ACME Inc", somePoints, noPoints);
int somePoints = card3[1];
```

is that you've declared the name `somePoints` twice. First as an array, then as an `int` variable.

Just pick a different name for the variable, e.g.

```
int aPoint = card3[1];
```